# How to fix a text widget length to a specific length then should keep breaking to the next Line

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i have a text widget that contain text, the text does not not overflow but i want to fix it to a specific length then multi line.

so if i fix the length to to 5, immediately it is more than 5 or get to 5 he should break to the next line

here is my code:

```
ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: recentChats.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          //final sender = recentChats[index].sender;
                          final auth = recentChats[index].sender.id;
                          final msg = recentChats[index].content;
                          //final timestamp = recentChats[index].time;
                          bool check = auth == 1 ? true : false;
                          return Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 15,
                              vertical: 10,
                            ),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: check
                                  ? CrossAxisAlignment.end
                                  : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: check ? Colors.indigo : Colors.white,
                                    borderRadius: check
                                        ? BorderRadius.only(
                                            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                                            topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                                            topRight: Radius.circular(30),
                                          )
                                        : BorderRadius.only(
                                            bottomRight: Radius.circular(30),
                                            topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                                            topRight: Radius.circular(30),
                                          ),
                                  ),
                                  child: Text(
                                    msg,
                                    style: GoogleFonts.raleway(
                                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                                        color:
                                            check ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        }),
```

what i am trying to achieve:

[image: the image i am trying to achieve]

i have try using maxLine but is not achieving what i want....

this is what my code is getting

[image: here is my code result]
thanks

Comment: your question is not clear, could you post what you are getting now? do you want the width of the text to be no more than 5 or the line count to be no more than 5?

Comment: i have update the question @YounssAITMOU

Comment: the text is too long so i want the text should be breaking when the length get to 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try wrapping your text in a `ConstrainedBox`:

```dart
//...
child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 50), //<-- set the max width here
        child: Text(
          msg,
          style: GoogleFonts.raleway(
            textStyle: TextStyle(
              color: check ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
//...
```